# Create wrapper of classes in apex class

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, wrapper-class

Hi everybody I want to instance an apex class in my LWC so I founded that in the apex class I have to create a wrapper. My apex class I have inner classes like these ones:

```
public class HospitalClass{
    public Change c;
    public class Change{
             public RequestData requestData;
             public Client client;
             public String comments;
             public DocumentsRegister documentRegister;
             public void getChildNode(){...}
             other methods...
    }
    public class Client {
       public IdClient idClient;
       public Name name;
       public List<Telephone> telephone;
       public void getChildNode(){...}
       other methods...
    }
}
```

In this case I dont know who to do the wrapper in this class to be able to be instanced from the js LWC. Could anybody help?

Comment: Can you add more details like how are you trying to pass this data to lwc?

Answer (score 1):

**Simple rules**

You need to know that:

- Object in LWC (.js) => `Map<Object, Object>` in Apex or **Apex Wrapper**
- Array in LWC (.js) => `List<Object>` in Apex

Those structures can be combined and nested.

**What next?**

You can create objects in LWC:

```js
const myWrapper = {
   c: {
      requestData: {}, //RequestData
      client: {
         idClient: '',
         name: '',
         telephone: [
            {}, {} //Telephone
         ]
      },
      comments: '',
      documentRegister: {} //DocumentsRegister
   }

};

// Invoke apex

myApexMethod({ params: myWrapper})
.then(() => {})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```java
public class MyApexController {

   @AuraEnabled
   public static void myApexMethod(HospitalClass params) {
       System.debug(params); 
       // Here you have access to all properties from HospitalClass class 
       // Properties will be set via LWC
   }
}
```